# Why does connection to SQL Server on a Docker container doesn't work? (macOS)

Tags: sql-server, docker, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Core Framework and I keep getting an error when connecting to the SQL Server. **Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..**

I'm following Microsoft's official [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SryQxUeChMc) and I'm on the first video and I'm using the [second](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/ef-core-for-beginners/blob/main/notes/1-getting-started/connection-strings.md) connection string provided by microsoft. The one I'm supposed to use is the second one, but I've used both and neither have worked. After searching the internet I've came to the conclusion that the issue has to do with the connection string, but I've tried many version of the same connection string (double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, etc) and none of them have worked.

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

`Login failed for user 'sa'` means one of four things:

1. The connection string does not have the right password for the sa account
   *(You **should** be setting your own password on that account and expect to change that part of the connection string).*
2. The `sa` account is disabled on the server.
   *(This is a best practice. You **should** disable the built in sa account and have your own admin account instead. Note it's common for vendor products to prohibit this, though :( ).*
3. Sql authentication is not enabled on the server (it's using Windows Authentication).
4. You're connecting to a different SQL Server instance than expected.
   *You did reach some SQL Server or the error message would be different, but it might be a* different instance *than expected, even on the same computer.*

Comment: the password I've set when running the SQL server image is the same as the one I'm putting when I try to change the admin password, but I get the same error when trying to connect to the database. So, I'm 95% sure #1 is not it.

Comment: Also I don't know if I understand really well, but I think the sa account is already enabled since according to Microsoft's [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash)  it's created during the setup. So I don't think it's #2 either

Comment: Finally what do you mean by `Sql authentication is not enabled on the server ` because I highly doubt that Microsoft would release a tutorial that cannot be used by macOS users and not say it upfront

Comment: SQL Server supports more than one different authentication mode. One of those (the default) is sql authentication, which is a traditional username + password. The other common mode is Windows Authentication, which uses a Windows login token to authenticate the user. This is especially useful in conjunction with Active Directory, but it's also good if the entire application (database + front end) will all live on the same computer. macOs is definitely not able to use that authentication mode.

Comment: The sa user is always an sql authentication user and it's possible this installation does not have the support for sql authentication enabled.